# C++ Auto deduction of template type argument

Tags: c++, templates

As part of my messaging library, I use a construct like this to send a message (struct)

```
tMsgVolumeChanged oMsg;
[...]
oMsg.vSend<tMsgVolumeChanged>();
```

with the vSend() method defined in the base class (from which tMsgVolumeChanged and all other messages is derived) as

```
struct tMsgBase
{
            tMsgBase() {}
  virtual  ~tMsgBase() {}

  template <class T> void vSend() { 
    poGetMessageDispatcher()->boDispatch<T>( *static_cast<T *>(this) );
  } 
}

struct tMsgVolumeChanged : tMsgBase
{
}
```

I was hoping that the vSend statement could be reduced to

```
tMsgVolumeChanged oMsg;
[...]
oMsg.vSend();
```

with the compiler auto-deducing the type argument to the template, but that won't compile ("couldn't deduce template parameter T").

Is there a neat "trick" that could be used to do this? Or am I simply making a basic mistake?

Comment: please post a [mcve]. What does `tMsgVolumeChanged` return? It can deduce the type from `oData.bVolume` and return appropriate object on which you only need to call `vSend()`. There are too little details to give a full answer

Comment: and please mention, which compiler version and c++ version you are using.

Comment: This asks for [CRTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: I have removed the oData.bVolume argument as that isn't relevant to the example.  The type T that I want to be auto deduced is the type of the message I am trying to send, so that I don't have to type it both when instantiating the struct and when sending it.  Given that the compiler knows the type of oMsg I would expect it to also be able to deduce the type T?

Compiler is GCC (with STM32CubeIDE 1.0.3) and c++ version is C++14

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Would you be able to help with an example?  I've tried CRTP but didn't make much headway in this particular instance.  Using the pattern elsewhere just fine.

Comment: You'd just make `vSend` not a template, and in it, instead of `T` use the template parameter of the whole class (which must become a template because of CRTP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `tMsgBase` polymorphically, you will have to have some overhead in the derived classes.

```
struct tMsgBase
{
            tMsgBase() {}
  virtual  ~tMsgBase() {}
  virtual void send() = 0;
protected:
  template <class T> void vSend(T * self) { 
    poGetMessageDispatcher()->boDispatch<T>( *self );
  } 
}

struct tMsgVolumeChanged : tMsgBase
{
    void send() override { vSend(this); }
}
```

That's an arguably appropriate place for a macro

```
#define MSG_BASE_SEND_IMPL void send() override { vSend(this); }

struct tMsgVolumeChanged : tMsgBase
{
    MSG_BASE_SEND_IMPL
}
```

Otherwise you can use the [CRTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

```
template <class T>
struct tMsgBase
{
            tMsgBase() {}
  virtual  ~tMsgBase() {}
  void vSend() { 
    poGetMessageDispatcher()->boDispatch<T>( *static_cast<T *>(this) );
  } 
}

struct tMsgVolumeChanged : tMsgBase<tMsgVolumeChanged>
{
}
```